# What all files do I need to publish for this extension, and will a computer without NodeJS be able to run it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension

So I was making an extension using this [template](https://github.com/fregante/browser-extension-template) and I wanted to know what files i'll need to publish for the final extension. The extension converts texts to emoji, similar to discord, so when you type ": sob:" it converts it to . I'm using NodeJS to download an emoji dictionary and so also wanted to know if itd work on a computer without this dictionary.

My code:

```
import emo from "emoji-dictionary";

let input_colon = false;

const look_for = /:([^\s]*):/gi;

document.body.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea")).forEach((input) => {
        Array.from(input.value.matchAll(look_for)).forEach((emo_input) => {
            const emoji = emo.getUnicode(emo_input[0]);
            if (emoji == undefined) {
            } else {
                input.value = input.value.replace(emo_input[0], emoji);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish on browsers for production, you should zip source directory. Or to publish for test on your browser, you can just add source directory which has manifest, background or etc. The files to publish are manifest.json, content.js, background.js which are related to manifest.json.

For the [template](https://github.com/fregante/browser-extension-template) you can add `./distribution` directory on `chrome://extensions` page after what you want to code. There shows the doc [this](https://github.com/fregante/browser-extension-template#-build-locally).

Comment: I did test on my browser, and it works. So when zipping, I should only zip the source file and not the other ones, like node modules etc? I was just worried about if it would work on a computer without NodeJS.

Comment: npm does not need for executing ext on chrome. You are afraid that if the extension not works without npm. I guess the owner added npm letting the extension work with ES6. The owner may use module bundler like web pack so npms may be added up into `distribution` directory.

Comment: Only `distribution` of zip is needed for publishing on browsers after you coding what you want to add and buliding. Npm is just for helping building for ES6 environment and maybe other.

Comment: If you have questions to get accurate answers then hope you ask [here](https://github.com/fregante/browser-extension-template/issues). Or [this forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions) is helpful too. Of course asking to stack overflow is welcome too.

Comment: Happy to be helpful :) If you think the question is solved then please to select my answer!